# Headers and cherrypy redirct

Tags: redirect, header, cherrypy

I was wondering if anybody knew how i can pass a header (basic auth and x-something) to "HTTPredirect"?

I have tried

cherrypy.request.headers['X-Transmission-Session-Id'] = ''

Answer (score 0):

If you need to protect your app or some of its URLs with Basic Auth, you should use [Basic Auth tool](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy.lib.html#module-cherrypy.lib.auth_basic). For sending headers you should use response's headers, `cherrypy.response.headers`, not request's.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cherrypy


userpassdict  = {'user': 'Pa$$wD'}
checkpassword = cherrypy.lib.auth_basic.checkpassword_dict(userpassdict)

config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/protected' : {
    'tools.auth_basic.on'            : True,
    'tools.auth_basic.realm'         : 'Walled garden',
    'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword' : checkpassword
  }
}


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    cherrypy.response.headers['X-Read-The-Docs'] = 'http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/'
    return 'Custom header example'

  @cherrypy.expose  
  def protected(self):
    return 'Protected content'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the response headers, not the request headers.

```
cherrypy.response.headers['X-Transmission-Session-Id'] = ""
```